# Android Closing App problem?

Tags: android

when close the home button in android device the application closed this is normal , but when return back to my app it start from where i close it, I want the app to start from the beginning screen ? 
For example : I have 2 screen (Activity)
screen 1: Home screen 
screen 2 : Activity#2

when I close app and I'm at screen 2 then start app again it opens screen 2 , but I want it to open screen 1 : Home screen 
Hope it is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing home button does not close the app. Pressing back button does close it.

Comment: Then u need to reinit in `onResume()`